# Vast difference in query execution explanation

Tags: ruby, arrays

Why does there seems to be such a vast difference in the time it takes to run these two queries? I am using Capybara to iterate over all the anchor tags on report section of a page and then place each value into an array so I can check the values.

```
@links = page.all('table.report > tbody > tr > .col_7 > a')
@links.map(&:text) # This takes approx 20 seconds to go through 239 results
@links.map { |l| l['title'] } # This takes about 3 seconds
```

Why is there such a big difference? I am looking to understand the main differences between each variation of the map function.

Comment: Did you try comparing that with `@links.map { |l| l.text }`? I think it's more about the diferrent type of DOM scanning you have to do for each than about the different "variations of the map function".

Comment: What I mean is, the title is just a tag attribute -- it should have already have that stored in the link object instance. `#text` is probably a method that scans through all child nodes recursively, extracting their text content.

Comment: thanks, think i understand it a little more now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be about the type of DOM scanning you have to do for each rather than about the different "variations of the map function".
Presumably, the title is just a tag attribute that will already have been stored in the `link` object instance by the time you try to retrieve it with `#[]()`, whereas `#text` is most likely a method that will recursively scan the child nodes of each link and extract text from each.

`#map(&:text)` and `#map {|item| item.text }`, aren't really two "variations of the map function." They're the exact same version. What the unary `&` does to a non-proc object that isn't a block is:

1. it calls `#to_proc` on it, which in case of symbol `:symbol` will yield an equivalent of `Proc.new {|item| item.symbol }`
2. it converts the proc acquired in step one to a block, which in case of symbol `:symbol` will yield an equivalent of `{|item| item.symbol}`

(See **The Unary &** section in http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/)

So as far as `#map` is concerned, it was invoked with `@links.map { |item| item.text }` when you did `@links.map(&:text)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@links.map(&:text)
```

When calling map on an ActiveRecord::Relation, the db is hit and all the @link(s) are returned (but not processed)

by invoking (&:text) however, each object must be constructed and subsequently, the text() method called on each of them

```
@links.map { |l| l['title'] }
```

While I am not certain, I believe a query optimizer can easily modify this to be: @links.pluck(:title) which would result in one db hit which would consequently return all the link titles (obviously being faster than constructing each query) Even if that is not the case, we are just extracting the attribute :title from the object without the need for constructing it

Comment: thanks for the answer, im not using a db in this instance but I see what you are saying

Comment: @link is not an ActiveRecord::Base